# Get resources folder path consistently across test and production code

Tags: java

The following decodes a base64 string and saves it into a file under  `resources/images` folder.

```
private final static String IMAGE_FOLDER = new File("resources/images").getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath();

public static String decodeBase64AndSaveImage(String data) throws IOException, BadRequestException {
    try {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String base64Image = data.split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
        String imageId = generateRandomKey(15);
        File imageFile = new File(IMAGE_FOLDER + File.separator + imageId);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", imageFile);
        return imageId;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Bad image data");
    }
}
```

The `images` folder is located under `/home/user/workspace/myproject/src/main/resources/images`, but when I run the test, the value for the `IMAGE_FOLDER` is `/home/user/workspace/myproject/resources/images`

I can understand that in the production environment there's no `src/main` folder anymore. But how can I have a consistent approach across production and test environments ?

**Note 1**

The test is failing

**Note 2**

I tried `ClassLoader` approach:

`Classname.class.getClass().getResource("filename.png")` but it returns null.

Comment: Don't attempt writing anything into a directory inside the project structure. Your classes will eventually end up in a jar or war or something, and you surely don't expect it to unpack itself at runtime to add a file to it's structure. Instead, keep the directory path external and configurable, via a simple configuration file or an env variable like [Kirby's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665880/294657)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application writes data, I recommend that the variable containing the target directory path be maintained *outside* your project code. I suggest using an environment variable. If the path were stored in environment variable IMG_DIR, you could access this information from your Java code with `System.getenv("IMG_DIR")`. Having this configuration item external to your JAR makes it trivially simple to move the JAR to any execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the path to `resources` directory is relative to the executable.

So, the best approach would be to generate your executable to `debug` or `release` folder. The respective build folder will contain the `resources` directory also to be used by the executable.

Technically, your build system should handle these things and in production your installer should take care of these configuration for successful execution.

Comment: What does this mean "So, the best approach would be to generate your executable to debug or release folder. "? what should I do in practice ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: That means your build system should take care of these things. The final `JAR` should contain all the relevant dependencies. And, in your code, you'd be referring to the resources like `./resources/images/abc.jpg`, `./config/test.conf`, etc.

Comment: I get the following error when I use ./resources/images/ as the path: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./resources/images/3g66l6his99h8pm (No such file or directory)`

Comment: writing to `./` writes to the project root folder. I want to write to the resources folder both in the production and test environment. Right now it fails the test.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: Why the path is different in development and production? And, what is `3g66l6his99h8pm`?

Comment: it's the file name. in the development it's under `src/main/resources`. in the test environment it's `/resources`. Apparently there's no `/src/main` in the test environment (and production) right ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: Most probably there would not be a `/src/main` if the project is properly configured to generate final executable at another path. But, why there's no `extension` associated with this filename? Is it without an `extension` e.g. `.jpg`, `.png`, etc.?

Comment: that's not a concern. it is a png that I want to create in the resources folder.